# React Load Component on Navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to fetch content from server on every Router.

`Navigation.js`

```
import { Component } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
export class Navigation extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loading: false,
      all_nav: [
        {
          menu_name: "News 1",
          menu_items_id: "31"
        },
        {
          menu_name: "News 2",
          menu_items_id: "32"
        },
        {
          menu_name: "News 3",
          menu_items_id: "33"
        }
      ]
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.state.all_nav.map((name, key) => (
          <li key={key}>
            <Link to={`news/${name.menu_items_id}`}>{name.menu_name}</Link>
          </li>
        ))}
        <hr />
        <li>
          <Link to="/">Home</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
```

Navigation.js contains list of navigation that is used to route the content.

`Index.js`

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { App } from "./App";
import { NewsList } from "./NewsList";

window.React = React;

render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <div>
      <Route exact path="/" title="App Title" render={props => <App />} />

      <Route path="/news/:filter" render={props => <NewsList {...props} />} />
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

`NewsList.js`

```js
import { Component } from "react";
import {Navigation} from './Navigation'
export class NewsList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loading: false,
      post_record: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    // console.log(this.props.match.params.filter)
    Promise.all([
      fetch("https://binodgiri.com.np/api/news_listing.php", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          param: this.props.match.params.filter
        })
      })
    ])
      .then(([all_post_api]) => Promise.all([all_post_api.json()]))
      .then(([post_data]) =>
        this.setState({
          loading: false,
          post_record: post_data
        })
      );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello Content</h1>
        {
          this.state.post_record.menu_name

        }
        <hr />
        <Navigation />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

`NewsList.js` is main rendering section, according to :filter id the content should be fetched from server "https://binodgiri.com.np/api/news_listing.php"

What I really want to do is::

If I click News 1 or anyother News at first. It renders perfectly. And if I want to Navigation to News 2 or other Nothing Happens

Here is the sandbox link : 
https://codesandbox.io/s/vykxvp17j7

Thank-you in advance.

Comment: This is because, `componentDidMount` wont be called when clicking the `Link`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add this logic.
Since `componentDidMount` is already mounted on first link click, it wont be called second time, hence you need to add following lifecycle function. (This is the quick fix, you can also rearrange the your logic for better performance.)

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.match.params.filter !== prevProps.match.params.filter) {
      Promise.all([
       fetch("https://binodgiri.com.np/api/news_listing.php", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        param: this.props.match.params.filter
      })
    })
  ])
    .then(([all_post_api]) => Promise.all([all_post_api.json()]))
    .then(([post_data]) =>
      this.setState({
        loading: false,
        post_record: post_data
      })
    );    
   }
}
```

In `Navigation.js`

```
<Link to={`/news/${name.menu_items_id}`}>{name.menu_name}</Link>
```

Comment: It worked perfectly, Also can you also point out something about "rearrange the your logic for better performance"

Comment: One is, in two places same fetch statements are written, try to write in one function and use it.

Comment: yes, absolutely in the process of solving output I completely forgot. 
and would be kind enough to let me know what are other performances issues that can be fixed ?